# Does cats-effect IO.orElse only work on delay IO and not pure IO?

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I'm trying to find heuristics/rules that let me predict correct behaviour.

I did a few experiments and is confused why sometimes i get eager while other times lazy evaluation when using orElse to chain various combinations of pure/delay and values inside them.

Docs for IO.orElse at https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/IO.html is not clear.

I'm running examples in `sbt console`
Based on build.sbt i'm using `scalaVersion    := "3.2.2"` and `"cats-effect"      % "3.4.10"`

All lazy answers are evaluated by chaining `unsafeRunSync()` like

```
scala> IO.pure(1).orElse(
     | IO.pure(2)).unsafeRunSync()
val res53: Int = 1
```

**Questions**

**Example 1**

```
scala> IO.pure(1).orElse(
     | IO.pure(2))
val res45: cats.effect.IO[Int] = IO(...)
```

If IO.pure(1) executes eagerly, why does chaining two pures give lazy output?

**Example 2**

```
scala> IO.pure(throw new Exception).orElse(
     | IO.pure(2))
java.lang.Exception
  ... 62 elided
```

If two pures should be lazily evaluated, why does throwing exception in 1st pure immediately return the exception?  (throwing only in 2nd pure returns the lazy evaluated IO)

Based on first 2 examples, it seems to me that for orElse to work as a fallback tool, the first IO should always be a delay?

**Example 3**

```
scala> IO.delay(throw new Exception).orElse(
     | IO.pure(2)).unsafeRunSync()
val res62: Int = 2
```

**Example 4**

```
scala> IO.delay(throw new Exception).orElse(
     | IO.delay(2)).unsafeRunSync()
val res63: Int = 2
```

Both example 3 and 4 return the same before and after `unsafeRunSync`.
How then do I choose to use pure or delay in the 2nd IO (orElse input)?

Does this depend on the meaning of the input?
For example if i want to hardcode a 2 i should use pure, and if i want to call some possibly failing function, i should use delay?

Answer (score 3):

> If IO.pure(1) executes eagerly, why does chaining two pures give lazy output?

The difference between `pure` and `delay` is in the evaluation of the parameter, not the `IO` itself. You'll always get an `IO` as output until you run it either with an `unsafe*` variant or within `IOApp`.

See the difference in the signatures:

```
def delay[A](thunk: => A): IO[A]

def pure[A](value: A): IO[A]
```

`delay` accepts a *by-name* parameter, which only evaluates when it's used, versus `pure` which will evaluate its parameter immediately. For a literal value `1`, there isn't really a difference, but for anything that can perform an effect, there is a huge difference, as seen in your examples.

> If two pures should be lazily evaluated, why does throwing exception in 1st pure immediately return the exception? (throwing only in 2nd pure returns the lazy evaluated IO)

The first `pure` eagerly evaluates its parameter, which throws the exception. But for `orElse`, take a look at its signature:

```
def orElse[B >: A](other: => IO[B]): IO[B]
```

It accepts another by-name parameter, meaning that it accepts *something that evaluates to an `IO[B]`*. This prevents the second from throwing immediately.

> Based on first 2 examples, it seems to me that for orElse to work as a fallback tool, the first IO should always be a delay?

If it's not a pure value, yes. Meaning, you shouldn't use `IO.pure` with non-constants.

> Does this depend on the meaning of the input?

Yes, `pure` is only for constant, non-side effecting things.

Answer (score 1):

> If IO.pure(1) executes eagerly, why does chaining two pures give lazy output?

Because the design has a parent trait (IO) and many of these cases are actually using child classes to represent different actions:

```
private[effect] final case class Pure[+A](value: A) extends IO[A] {
  def tag = 0
  override def toString: String = s"IO($value)"
}

private[effect] final case class Error(t: Throwable) extends IO[Nothing] {
  def tag = 1
}

private[effect] final case class Delay[+A](thunk: () => A, event: TracingEvent)
  extends IO[A] {
  def tag = 2
}
...
```

Calling a method goes back to the parent class where the methods are defined, and has no knowledge of whether its Pure vs. Delay, so it has to treat everything as if its delayed.

> If two pures should be lazily evaluated, why does throwing exception in 1st pure immediately return the exception? (throwing only in 2nd pure returns the lazy evaluated IO)

Pure is supposed to be used for safe values only.
Your statement:

> For example if i want to hardcode a 2 i should use pure, and if i want to call some possibly failing function, i should use delay?

is correct.  Pure is meant for simple values.
Delay is meant for operations that can have side effects, or fail.
You can think of Delay as a temporary state the puts it into either Pure or Error when evaluated.
and if you follow that through to its conclusion than:

> Based on first 2 examples, it seems to me that for orElse to work as a fallback tool, the first IO should always be a delay?

is also correct, as if you can't fail then `orElse` doesn't make much sense.

I'd recommend browsing the [source code](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/series/3.x/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala), it can be pretty accessible.
Also check out the [Getting Started Guide](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/getting-started)